# Rename wxTreeCtrl item

Tags: wxwidgets

I want the normal rename on double click and/or F2

So:

```
  new wxTreeCtrl(this,IDC_Tree,wxPoint(-1,-1),wxSize(-1,-1),
    wxTR_HAS_BUTTONS | wxTR_LINES_AT_ROOT | wxTR_EDIT_LABELS);
```

Double click does not rename.  ( it displays the children of a parent node )

F2 does not rename

What does work is

- click node to select it
- press F2 key
- click node again - now I am able to type in a new name

It does the job, I suppose, but I don't want to have to explain this to every user.

wxWidgets v2.9, C++, windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`F2` doesn't work out of the box for `wxTreeCtrl` (it does work for `wxDataViewCtrl` though), you'll need to handle it and call `EditLabel()` yourself.

Double click is never used for renaming the items, only for activating them. What works for renaming is "slow click", i.e. a click on an already selected item which comes *late* enough to *not* count as a second click of a double click. This is how it works in the standard Windows treeview control and in `wxTreeCtrl` too.

Comment: You are right, a ... very ... slow ... double click works.  Presumably, I could speed this up a bit with mouse settings.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just catch an event of type `wxEVT_COMMAND_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED` and then use  [wxTreeCtrl::EditLabel](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_tree_ctrl.html#a08d88a76e02f59001766bc90e20016b7) to start the editor?

Comment: I believe so.  But is it necessary?  Shouldn't this work out of the box by setting the  wxTR_EDIT_LABELS style?  It almost does, except for that one last click on the item after pressing F2